# Make file open with different program

Tags: windows, java

I accidentally opened a Java file with Firefox and now I cannot change this... How can I make JCreator default again?

Here is example of my problem:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is simply because you changed the default for that registered filetype, this is easy to change back.

In any explorer window (you can use that one you have open in the picture) go to:

- Tools -> Folder Options -> "File Types" tab
- Scroll down the list to find the `.java` extension
- Highlight the `.java` selection.
- Where it says "Opens With:", click the "Change..." button and choose JCreator.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- Right-click on the file.
- Click "Open With". If this opens a submenu, select "Browse" (I think).
- Select "Select a program from a list of installed programs".
- Out of the list, select JCreator.
- Check the checkbox that says "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file", and hit Enter.
- You're done.

I'd post a screenshot, but I'm running Vista so mine is a bit different. If anyone is willing to contribute, feel free to leave a link to the screenshot in a comment and I will edit my post. :)

Comment: I try this but checkbox is grey

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The only time that has ever happened with me is with files with no extension. Oh well, I'll keep the answer here because it's easier than the other suggestion, IMO.